# Anyone knows a jQuery plugin that returns pages with comparing anchor hash and navigation?

Tags: jquery, html, url, jquery-plugins, navigation

This is the site http://www.numidia.it/ it has a very cool navigation and i wonder if there's a plugin that does something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jQuery address plugin](http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/) does that and furthermore you can define url without hashes(#).

Here is an example: http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/samples/express/portfolio

But if you want to do it yourself, you can use `window.location.hash` value.

```
<a href="#/home">Home</a>
<a href="#/about">About</a>

<div class="pages homePage">...</div>
<div class="pages aboutPage">...</div>

//response for page load
var anchor = window.location.hash;
if( anchor === '#/home' ) {
   $('.pages').hide();
   $('.homePage').show();
}else if( anchor === '#/about' ) {
   $('.pages').hide();
   $('.aboutPage').show();
}

//response for a clicked
$('a').click(function() {
    var target = $(this).attr('href');
    if( target === '#/home' ) {
       $('.pages').hide();
       $('.homePage').show();
    }else if( target === '#/about' ) {
       $('.pages').hide();
       $('.aboutPage').show();
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks barlas, i guess that .pages and .homePage are divs for my content right?